# Go time.Tick vs time.NewTicker

Tags: go

I am new to Go and started learning recently. I have come across tickers and timers. In the tickers, we can create a ticker in two ways

```
throttler := time.Tick(time.Millisecond * 50)
<- throttler

throttler := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
<- throttler.C
```

What is the difference between them other than syntax?

Comment: Go docs are extremely easy to read.  Many questions like this can be answered by clicking on the function definition within the docs site. https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [time.Tick documentation](https://godoc.org/time#Tick):

> Tick is a convenience wrapper for NewTicker providing access to the ticking channel only. While Tick is useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks".