# How to run a heartbeat function

Tags: linux, go, websocket, gorilla, heartbeat

I seen tons of questions with responses on how to periodically run a function. The **problem**? They all lock the program from moving on.

What I need?
I have a websocket and I have a `for {}` that keeps reading for msg's and now and every 10 secs I need to run a call to the heartbeat function, with out interrupting the program or stop reading the chat.
I am thinking in using some approaches but none of them seem clean/nice using channels, but I think someone more experienced may have a good and simpler approach to this.

I was using something like this but it never gets to the end of the function to return what I need for the program to continue.

```
timerCh := time.Tick(time.Duration(10) * time.Second)
  for range timerCh {
    go Heartbeat(ws)
}

return ws
```

I am looking for a way to be able to call Heartbeat every 10 secs with out:

1. calling it repetitively every time I read for incoming websocket connections
2. with out locking the program.

Some context,
This is for a bridge chat, so I open a websocket, keep reading from this, and only sent to the other chat when is a chat msg, in the mean time I need to sent a heartbeat with out locking this.
What do I have now?
now it all works, but after 30 secs or so my websocket closes:

```
2020/07/01 20:59:09 Error read: websocket: close 1000 (normal)
```

Comment: Why not put the for loop in the goroutine?

Comment: the one that reads from the websocket? because it will do go Hearbeat(ws) continuously and I do not want that, only every 10 secs or so. if I add a timer.Tick then stops the main go routine...

Comment: Isn't that why you're using a ticker, so that it only runs every 10 seconds? You also should have some way to cancel this (plus you should not use `time.Tick`, because as the documentation states, you can't shut it down)

Comment: hmm maybe thats the issue, Im a newbee, can you offer me an example that will not lock the rest of my program?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Go with @JimB's answer! This was just meant to show that the timer should be managed outside of the `main` goroutine.

Your heartbeat function should manage its own timer. Something like this should work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go heartbeat()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("main is still going")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    }
}

func heartbeat() {
    for {
        timer := time.After(time.Second * 10)
        <-timer
        fmt.Println("heartbeat happened!")
    }
}
```

This example will print from `main` every 3 seconds and from heartbeat every `10` and will terminate after 30 seconds.

Comment: @rek2: you should not use a `time.After` as a sleep, nor should you be using sleep here at all. Your original idea to use a ticker was correct, you just want to be able to stop it.

Comment: I was just using `sleep` in my toy example and by no means do I suggest adding a `sleep` to your code. @rek2 go with @JimB's approach below.

Comment: I don't mean the _actual_ sleep call, you're using `time.After` as a sleep, and using that where you should be using an interval timer.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to be able to shut down the ticker, so do not use `time.Tick`, rather use `time.NewTicker`.

If you move the entire for loop with the ticker into a goroutine, it will not block the main goroutine.

```
go func() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for range ticker.C {
        Heartbeat(ws)
        // return on error or cancellation
    }
}()
```

Comment: Does this compile? I'm seeing this in playground: `cannot range over ticker (type *time.Ticker)`

Comment: Heartbeat usually runs as long as the program is running. so it is not necessary to stop Tick because there is no need for GC. Tick should be fine for Heartbeat use case. see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856959/go-time-tick-vs-time-newticker#:~:text=time.Tick%20documentation